# misleading “Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated” warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fs

NodeJS gives me a warning

> (node:32600) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous
>   function without callback is deprecated.

when I run this ‘test’:

```
describe('whatever', () => {
  it('test simple', async () => {
    const dir = './build/fileTests';

    if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      console.log(`deleting ${dir}`);
      await fs.rmdir(dir);
    }
  });
});
```

Well, I would almost agree, that using async-functions without a callback is bad (since only within the cb you can know for sure, it happened, go on, etc...

... if it wasn't for my intentional use of the [ES7 `async`/`await`](http://rossboucher.com/await/), because they make it synchronous, so I can work with whatever I get... (in this special case, I could evade to [rmdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdirsync_path), but that's not my point...)

**so my Question: How can I get rid of warnings like these?**

– in a meaningful way, when working with async/await...
– dealing with the return value, as in `const r = ...` is not recognized as ‘callback handling’...

Comment: `async/await` don't make asynchronous code synchronous. It may _look_ like it, but it isn't.

Comment: this makes me think of callbacks as async lie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fs.rmdir does not return a promise object, that's why this code fails with swag. You have to promisify it , using a library or the node.js `promisify` method in `util` core module

Note: if you use this same approach for other **async** methods in the `fs` core module, it will fail

do this

```
const util = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");
const removeDir = util.promisify(fs.rmdir);

const rmDir = async () => {
   try {
      await removeDir("directory_name");
   } catch(ex) {
      console.error(ex)
   }
}
```

Just make sure you promisify it

**Edit:** declared a variable to hold the value of `uti.promisify(fs.rmdir)` as suggested by @bergi

**Edit:** Add error handling with `try .. catch` block

Comment: Notice you should put the `util.promisify` call outside of the `rmDir` function, and store the result.

Comment: Changes have been made. Thanks @Bergi.